# Make array in min max range according to member

Tags: php

This is my actual array.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [member] => 1
            [amount] => 50
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [member] => 500
            [amount] => 100
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [member] => 1000
            [amount] => 150
        )
     [3] => Array
        (
            [member] => 1000
            [amount] => 150
        )    
)
```

I want to make an array with range according to the next index array element member.
I.e my min. member count 1 and next index array element member count 500 So
**0 index** element range make **`[min_member] => 1`** and **`[max_member] => 499`**

Expected output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [min_member] => 1
            [max_member] => 499
            [amount] => 50
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [min_member] => 500
            [max_member] => 999
            [amount] => 100
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [min_member] => 1000
            [max_member] => 1499
            [amount] => 150
        )
     [3] => Array
        (
            [max_member] => 1500
            [amount] => 150
        )    
)
```

Comment: What have you tried so far ?

Answer (score 0):

I assume the last item is a typo (1000/1500?).

I loop the array and use key to get the next items member (-1) as the max and unset the member.
After the loop I unset item as that is by reference of the array, so any change of $item will change the array.

```
foreach($arr as $key => &$item){
    $item['min_member'] = $item['member'];
    if(isset($arr[$key+1]['member'])) $item['max_member'] = $arr[$key+1]['member']-1;
    unset($arr[$key]['member']);
}
unset($item);
Var_dump($arr);
```

Outputs:

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    ["amount"]=>
    int(50)
    ["min_member"]=>
    int(1)
    ["max_member"]=>
    int(499)
  }
  [1]=>
  array(3) {
    ["amount"]=>
    int(100)
    ["min_member"]=>
    int(500)
    ["max_member"]=>
    int(999)
  }
  [2]=>
  array(3) {
    ["amount"]=>
    int(150)
    ["min_member"]=>
    int(1000)
    ["max_member"]=>
    int(1499)
  }
  [3]=>
  &array(2) {
    ["amount"]=>
    int(150)
    ["min_member"]=>
    int(1500)
  }
}
```

https://3v4l.org/5GGo0